# Masstransit Jobconsumer change queue names Job, JobAttempt and JobType

Tags: masstransit

I am building a proof of concept with masstransit, rabbitmq and the jobconsumers. It is very nice and I am making progress. But there is one thing I cannot solve, that is changing the queue names of the queues Job, JobAttempt and JobType. I cannot find the right place to inject an endpointnameformatter. We are running multiple applications on a rabbitmq cluster and the jobs of the different solutions should not be mixed. So my question is where and how can a change the queue names?

I have tried:

```
services.AddMassTransit(mt =\>

    mt.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

    mt.AddConsumer\<LongJobConsumer\>(cfg =\>
    {
        cfg.Options\<JobOptions\<LongJobConsumer\>\>(options =\> options
            .SetJobTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
            .SetConcurrentJobLimit(1));
    });

    mt.SetEndpointNameFormatter(new DefaultEndpointNameFormatter("MyQueue", false));

    mt.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();
        cfg.Host(rabbitMqConfig.Host, host =>
        {
            host.Username(rabbitMqConfig.Username);
            host.Password(rabbitMqConfig.Password);
            host.Heartbeat(rabbitMqConfig.Heartbeat);
        });

        cfg.UseGlobalRetryPolicy();
        cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox();

        ServiceInstanceOptions options = new ServiceInstanceOptions()
            .EnableJobServiceEndpoints();
        cfg.ServiceInstance(options, instance =>
        {
            instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints();
            instance.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new DefaultEndpointNameFormatter("MyQueue", false));
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the endpoint names when configuring the job service endpoints:

```cs
instance.ConfigureJobServiceEndpoints(x =>
{
    x.JobServiceStateEndpointName = "job-type";
    x.JobServiceJobAttemptStateEndpointName = "job-attempt";
    x.JobServiceJobStateEndpointName = "job";
});
```